# Angular.js Client height

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, css, angularjs-directive

I have an angular.j app, which has a view and a directive.  The various views used have different client height.  I am trying to place a default background on the view, while various views have different page heights.

To place a background on the screen, I need to know the client window height, which is the minimum height that the background will be set to.  The height of the view, if this is bigger than the client height, the background would need expanding to cover the extra height.

The view:
index.html

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div main-container></div>
  <script src=......></script>
</body>
```

The view controller
js/app.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

myApp
    .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'views/home.html'
        })
        .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'
    });
}]);
```

The Home view
views/home.html

```
<div style="height: 2000px">
  <p>Home View content</p>
</div>
```

The view directive for main-container
js/directives/main.js

```
myApp.directive('mainContainer', ['$window', function($window) {
return {
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        scope.onResize = function() {
            var header = document.getElementsByClassName('main-container')[0];
            elem.windowHeight = $window.innerHeight - header.clientHeight - 80;
            $(elem).height(elem.windowHeight);                

        }
        scope.onResize();
        angular.element($window).bind('resize', function() {
            scope.onResize();
        })
    }}
}])
```

The view directive does not get the height of the view, it gets the client window height when ever the page is re-sized & refreshed.  I would like to also get the view height, so that I can set the height of the container background to either the client height or view height, which ever is the bigger.

I'd like to do is get the height of the view, as set in the home.html css, is there a way to do this?

Please assist.

Comment: I think `main-container`  directive should be placed on `ng-view` element..will solve your issue.

Comment: This is useful, I think my example is broken.  Having a further look into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you to put you directive attribute on `ng-view` element, also your directive needs some changes. In order call calculation function for height `scope.onResize` you need to call it on `element.on('load')` also will ensure that the every time view changes will call `scope.onResize` function.

**Directive**

```
myApp.directive('mainContainer', ['$window', function($window) {
return {
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        scope.onResize = function() {
            var header = document.getElementsByClassName('main-container')[0];
            elem.windowHeight = $window.innerHeight - header.clientHeight - 80;
            $(elem).height(elem.windowHeight);                

        }
        scope.onResize();
        angular.element($window).bind('resize', scope.onResize);
        //below function will call on view change in ng-view 
        element.on('load', function(){
           $scope.$apply(scope.onResize);
        })
    }}
}])
```